# how to write or insert function and update in sq-lite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void insertData(String cateogry, String status, String feedback,
            String date, Bitmap bitmap) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CATEGORY, cateogry);
        cv.put(STATUS, status);
        cv.put(FEEDBACK, feedback);
        cv.put(IMAGE, Utility.getBytes(bitmap));
        cv.put(DATE, date);
        db.insert(INFR_TABLE, CATEGORY, cv);


    }

    public void updateData(String cateogry, String status, String feedback,
            String date, Bitmap bitmap)

    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(CATEGORY, cateogry);
        cv.put(STATUS, status);
        cv.put(FEEDBACK, feedback);
        cv.put(IMAGE, Utility.getBytes(bitmap));
        cv.put(DATE, date);
        db.update(INFR_TABLE, cv,  "cateogry="+cateogry, null);

    }
```

this is update and insert funcation in sqlite i want when row of cateogry is alredy there  then update it with other value if not then insert . and i am calling like this way :

for(table)

```
            String data[] = dh.getAllCategory();

    if (Arrays.asList(data).contains("Table")) {
        dh.updateData("Table", t, j, "25.5.2014", BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    }

    else {
        dh.insertData("Table", t, j, "25.5.2014", BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    }
```

for(water) :

```
String data[] = dh.getAllCategory();
    // dh.deleteitem(11);
    if (Arrays.asList(data).contains("Table")) {
        dh.updateData("Water", t, j, "25.5.2014", BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    }

    else
    {
        dh.insertData("Water", t, j, "25.5.2014", BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    }
```

but every time its create new row and duplicate please help me where am doing wrong we have 2 class in on is for table and another for water. please tell

Comment: Small suggestion, please don't store image byte in SQLite database instead write image to external SDCard and refer that path in database.

Comment: Use **REPLACE INTO** instead of **INSERT INTO** or **UPDATE**. With `a single instruction` you will **insert a new row or update an existing one**.

Comment: @sector11 we have limited number of image 10 image only

Comment: how can u please update my function coz i tried this i am unable to do @DerGolem

Comment: Instead of using `db.insert()` or `db.update()`, you will use `execSQL()`

Comment: db.replace(INFR_TABLE, CATEGORY, cv);  we have to use like this ?@DerGolem

Comment: hmmm... yes, that might be an alternate solution to using `execSQL()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void insertData(String id, String cateogry, String status,
            String feedback, String date, Bitmap bitmap) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ID, id);
        cv.put(CATEGORY, cateogry);
        cv.put(STATUS, status);
        cv.put(FEEDBACK, feedback);
        cv.put(IMAGE, Utility.getBytes(bitmap));
        cv.put(DATE, date);
                db.insertWithOnConflict(INFR_TABLE, ID, cv,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            }
```

try this and Update i think it should work ..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining to two blocks of code you can maintain into a single block by using [insertWithOnConflict](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)).

> public long insertWithOnConflict (String table, String nullColumnHack,
>   ContentValues initialValues, int conflictAlgorithm)

In the conflictAlgorithm you can specify what if an conflict occurs while inserting the record here you can specify [CONFLICT_REPLACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_REPLACE)

According to docs,

> When a UNIQUE constraint violation occurs, the pre-existing rows that
>   are causing the constraint violation are removed prior to inserting or
>   updating the current row. Thus the insert or update always occurs. The
>   command continues executing normally. No error is returned.

so simply you can specify as

```
database.insertWithOnConflict(tablename, columnHack, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

it will inserts the record if it already exists otherwise it will update.

Comment: what will databasevalue and Table_coupn is tablename? what about null value we have to  update data if alredy exist on basis of cateogry  column

Comment: updated my answer Have look.    Set your data to the contentValues and provide it as parameter

Comment: db.insertWithOnConflict(INFR_TABLE, CATEGORY, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);  should is use like this @Kartheek

Comment: ya if the primary key already exists then it updates the record otherwise it will updates the existing one.